# Как в Webpack 5 разделять файлы html?

Tags: javascript, webpack

```json
{
    test: /\.html$/i,
    use: {
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
        interpolate: true
        }
    }

}
```

Приблизительно так это выглядело в 4-ой версии